# Connecting multiple circles using canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I'm trying to write a program that will draw a circle on the screen when the user clicks for the first time and then for every successive click it will draw another circle and connect it the first one to the new one with a straight line. I'm a bit stuck beyond drawing the circles based on user clicks.

Here's my code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  //alert("test");
 $scope.doClick = function(event){

 var x = event.clientX;
 var y = event.clientY;
 var offsetX = event.offsetX;
 var offsetY = event.offsetY;
 //alert(x, y, offsetX, offsetY);

 /// These are the 2 new lines, see you target the canvas element then apply it to getContext
 var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

  //draw a circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

};


});
```

Here's the link to the plnk

http://plnkr.co/edit/rYVLgB14IutNh1F4MN6T?p=preview

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the circles drawing nicely...here's how to do the connecting lines!

You can use compositing to draw your connecting lines **under previously drawn content**

[image]

In particular `ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over'` will cause your new connecting line to be drawn **under** previously drawn circles (and lines).

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var radius=10;
var lastX,lastY;

ctx.fillStyle='red';

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


function drawCircle(cx,cy){
  if(lastX){
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  drawCircle(mx,my);

  lastX=mx;
  lastY=my;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on the canvas to draw connected circles</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[ Added example where all new circles connect to the first ]**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var radius=10;
var lastX,lastY;

ctx.fillStyle='red';


$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


function drawCircle(cx,cy){
  if(lastX){
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
  }else{
    lastX=cx;
    lastY=cy;
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  drawCircle(mx,my);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on the canvas to draw connected circles</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: this almost does it just need all new circles to connect to the first circle. Not to each other.

Comment: Connecting just to the first circle is actually simpler than the original Demo. See my answer for a second Demo connecting everything to the first circle. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find your answer to connecting all of them to the first circle. Thanks a lot in any case.

Comment: It's the bottom code...after [Added example where all new circles connect to the first] ;-)

Comment: This seems amazing on your demo, but gives a slightly different behaviour on my plnkr.     http://plnkr.co/edit/rYVLgB14IutNh1F4MN6T?p=preview

Comment: I cleaned up the code but its still giving a slightly different behavior. Any idea why. Just don't seem to get what's wrong.